# Post-apocalyptic novel with teenage girl who survived in a bomb shelter built by her father

Tags: story-identification

Post-apocalyptic novel with smart teenage girl who survived in a bomb shelter built by her father.  She thinks she's the only one left, but isn't.  Probably from the 1970s.  I liked it then, curious what I'd think now.

Comment: Can you remember any actual events from the book, any description of the girl, her name, what kind of shelter it was, was it a nuclear attack or something elese?

Comment: There are way too many possible answers for us to get this through any method but random guesses unless we get more information.

Comment: Was there a parrot?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions; i'll look for "Z for Zachariah" and "Emergence" and update this after i'v read them.  As for additional details, my memory is not reliable and tends to mix up various stuff that i've read.  But no parrot.

Comment: I found a copy of "Z for Zachariah" and that's not it. Will look for "Emergence".

Comment: possibly the same as https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/183906/story-id-a-pre-teen-girl-who-is-a-genius-crosses-the-country-in-a-van

Answer (score 14):

[Emergence](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0553255193), by David Palmer?

It fits each of the points you provide:

- The main character is teenage girl (actually 11yo, but close enough)
- She has a super high IQ
- Survives in a bomb shelter under her home
- Ends up finding other people who are left

It's not from the 1970's though (1984)

Comment: It's worthwhile highlighting why you think this is the right answer in the event that your link stops working or changes

Comment: Please explain how this book "fits each of the points" the OP lists. In particular, this books was published in 1984, and the OP remembers 1970s, so it seems it *doesn't* fit at least one point the OP provides.

Comment: Apparently the novel is an expansion of David R. Palmer's [novelette](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?49534) of the same title, which was first published in 1981 *Analog*. I haven't read the novel, but the novelette is what the OP's description reminded me of.

Comment: Emergence had an interesting, condensed, writing style - like shorthand.  This should be memorable to whoever has read it.

Answer (score 8):

Possibly [*Z for Zachariah*](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/69477.Z_for_Zachariah) by Robert O'Brian. "Nuclear war has devastated America, except for the valley where Ann Burden has been living alone for over a year - until Loomis, a scientist in a radiation-proof suit, arrives." Published in 1976.

Comment: Good book, but it's the guy who survives in a bomb shelter. The girl just happens to live in a valley that is unaffected by the nuclear stuff.